# SQL Server 2005: Insert multiple rows with single query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, insert

This should be a fairly straightforward question, but I haven't been able to find a solid answer online. I'm trying to insert multiple rows into the same table, but with only one statement. The most popular I've seen online is the following, but I've read that it only works with SQL Server 2008:

```
INSERT INTO Table (Name, Location) VALUES
('Name1', 'Location1'),
('Name2', 'Location2'),
('Name3', 'Location3'), etc...
```

I'd prefer this method if it will work with SQL Server 2005, but I don't think it will. The other option, from what I've read, has to do with UNION ALL's following SELECT statements after the INSERT, which seems clunky. Does anyone know for sure the best syntax to do this in 2005?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yep. You have to use `UNION ALL`s in SQL Server 2005 to insert multiple rows in a SQL script in a single statement.

```
INSERT INTO Table 
  (Name, Location) 
SELECT 'Name1', 'Location1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Name2', 'Location2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Name3', 'Location3'
```

The other main alternative is to repeat the `Insert` statement multiple times which is even more verbose. You need to be careful to use Explicit transactions in this last case to avoid the overhead of many individual commits (and for atomicity reasons of course)

If you have lots of rows to insert you could use [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) to load it all in from a delimited file in one statement.

Finally if this is data already in the database that you are scripting out (perhaps to deploy on another server) the [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) addin has a "Generate Insert Statements" function that can generate these statements for you.

Comment: For the record, would you mind typing out an example using UNION ALL?

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, the key here is `UNION ALL`. For me, using a CTE keeps things looking a little cleaner e.g.

```
WITH NewStuff (Name, Location)
     AS
     (
      SELECT 'Name1', 'Location1' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Name2', 'Location2' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Name3', 'Location3' 
     )
INSERT INTO Stuff (Name, Location) 
SELECT Name, Location
  FROM NewStuff;
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the `union all` in sql server 2005.  To be honest, that's so clunky and ugly, I'd just use multiple `inserts` if I were you.  Wrap them in a single transaction and it's the same thing in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are your only options, unless you are inserting a lot of data and might want to explore a `BULK INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO Table (Name, Location)
SELECT 'Name1', 'Location1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Name2', 'Location2' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Name3', 'Location3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since MS SQLServer 2005 supports XML the best method I would suggest is a STORED PROCEDURE with an input parameter of XML type.
If you are working with .NET you can easily convert the DataSet to xml string using ds.GetXml() method and can be sent to the SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertLocation](@XML XML=NULL)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[TheLocations]
        ( [Name], [Location] )
   SELECT
        XTab.value('Name[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS[Name],
        XTab.value('Location[1]','nvarchar(200)') AS[Location]
    FROM @XML.nodes('TheLocations') XTab([XTab])
END
```