# insert multiple rows in single SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, union-all

I am trying to insert multiple rows with SQL statement.

For that i refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272487/sql-server-2005-insert-multiple-rows-with-single-query) question.

According to top scored answer in this qestion, i made following query:

```
INSERT INTO login
(LogInID,Password)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Name1','pass1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Name2','pass2'
```

But when i try to execute this one, it gives me error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
```

What can be the mistake in this query?

Is this a wrong approach?

Please help me.

**NOTE:** I am using SQL SERVER 2005

Comment: just remove first UNION ALL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to remove `UNION ALL` before the first `SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO login (LogInID,Password)
SELECT 'Name1','pass1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Name2','pass2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it does not provides an answer to your original question I think it's worth knowing that SQL Server provides another syntax using the VALUES syntax:

```
insert into login values
('Name1','pass1'), 
('Name2','pass2'),
('Name3','pass3')
```