# Insert SQL for multiple record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I get the error message when I run the following query in `MSSQL Server 2005`.

Error Message is `Incorrect syntax near ','`. I think query is ok. But I don't know why I get error.

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, EMP_NAME) VALUES ('E001', 'AAA'), ('E002', 'BBB');
```

SQL Server does not support?

Comment: is your ID can read string characters?

Comment: yes, it is sure both of columns is varchar

Comment: I think multiple inserts like that are supported in and above MSSQL Server 2008

Comment: Inserting multiple values with that syntax is introduced with SQL Server 2008. You have to go with `UNION ALL` in 2005. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272487/sql-server-2005-insert-multiple-rows-with-single-query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your DB is lower than `SQL Server 2008`

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, EMP_NAME) VALUES ('E001', 'AAA');
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, EMP_NAME) VALUES ('E002', 'BBB');
```

Comment: Omg, really? I thought that every database server support simple sql query like that. Thz for your providing.

Comment: @Parado, thz for message `If your DB is lower than SQL Server 2008`

Comment: Why did you delete [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17879677/458741) @Parado, it's correct. If you undelete I'd upvote.

Comment: @Ben Undeleted, but I'm looking for last and first position of char

Comment: @Ben Now I see it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `UNION ALL` -

```
INSERT INTO Person (id, EMP_NAME)
SELECT id = 'E001', EMP_NAME = 'AAA'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'E002', 'BBB'
```

Comment: Yes, I also use like that. Alternatively, I just change the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Person (id, EMP_NAME)
SELECT 'E001', 'AAA'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'E002', 'BBB'
```